# Is there a name for this sort of concave region, or points in it?

Tags: geometry, terminology, definition, surfaces, projective-geometry

I am wondering if there is a mathematical term for this, since I'm trying to search up algorithms that deal with these sort of points/regions, but I am having difficulty finding what I'm looking for.

Suppose you have a 3D surface. Indents like the ones highlighted in orange here consist of points that (aside from the boundary) will never appear on the edge of the surface's silhouette, and thus have no impact on said edge of the silhouette, when viewed from any position and any angle. My question is, does a name for such points/regions other than just "indents" exist?

[[image link]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAksL.png)

However, other "concavities", like the ones shown here, *do* affect the silhouette, and should not be included in any such definition.

[[image link]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg6p5.png)

This question is similar to [Name for a body that can be completely described using its silhouettes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838953/name-for-a-body-that-can-be-completely-described-using-its-silhouettes), which seems to be asking about the name of a body that does not contain any such regions. This is something I'd also be interested in, if anyone has such an answer (the original question has some answers in the comments, but they do not work very well for web searches). However, I'm more interested in names for the indents themselves, if such names exist.

Comment: I don't think there is a name, but those indents have no effect on the convex hull. So that is one way to describe them.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I suppose so, but the "indent" in the second image also has no effect on the convex hull, but does have an effect on the silhouette, so I'd still have to distinguish further.

Comment: My phrasing was unclear. In the 2nd example, there is a projection direction such that the shape and the hull of the shape differ. Whereas this is not the case in the 1st example: any projection of the shape and the same projection of the hull are identical.

Comment: Not sure whether it will help but there's a fair amount known about the extent to which knowledge of the projections of a convex set determines the set. I used to think about things like this but it would take me a while to find the relevant literature now.